# RewriteRule: different result depending on the PC

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this line in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test.mypage.eu [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://test.mypage.eu [R=301,L]
```

When i do the request, it's doing the redirection OK from one PC but from another one no. Any idea what can be the problem?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely browser cache. Make sure you clear your cache on the browser that is misbehaving. Since a redirect is issued by the server, the results are not ordinarily going to vary from one client to another.